# Duplicate Based on Multi-Coulmn - Only Keep the Earliest and Latest Value

Tags: excel, duplicates, conditional-formatting

Below is an example of an Excel sheet I'm working with:

[image]

Basically, I'm trying to delete the duplicate rows by matching ID, Date and Type.  If ID, Date and Type are the same, then, I want to only keep the record with the earliest Time in case of Type = In and the latest Time in case of Type = Out.

So, for example, in the case of ID = 1, there are 3 records for In, I only want to keep the one where Time is: 8:01 as this is the earliest.  The other 2 records should be deleted.

Similarly, in the case of ID 3, I want to keep the record where Time = 18:05 as this is the later time out of the 2.

Can this be achieved by Conditional Formatting or is it more complex than that?

Many thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional Formatting does not to me look the best approach. Depending upon how often required (frequently, and VBA may be better) I suggest:

1. Add a sequential index (so can be sorted back to original order, if required).
2. Sort on Time (Smallest to Largest) within Type.
3. Select Type `Out` and sort Largest to Smallest.
4. Select all, in Remove Duplicates uncheck all but `Name`, `Date` and `Type` and OK.
5. Resort and delete index, if desired.